# Semantic UI toggle button not appearing correctly

Tags: html, css, togglebutton, semantic-ui

I am using Semantic-UI for my web app and am using the [Toggle](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/form.html#checkbox) checkbox.

The way it should appear as show in the docs is show below (Green toggle):

[image]

However on my site it actually shows like this:

[image]

I haven't touched the CSS for it so I have no idea why it is appearing like this.
Here is the HTML I added for the toggle button:

```
 <div class="inline field">
    <div class="ui toggle checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <label>Toggle</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Does anyone know why it doesn't appear as it should.

Comment: you probably have a css who is overriding it's properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though I am using a previous version of Semantic UI so some of the CSS is different to how we see it on their website. After digging through the Semantic UI css files I managed to get my checkbox looking like the first picture on this post. 
I first downloaded the latest version of Semantic UI and then I went into the `semantic.css` file for that version and went to the Toggle section.

The toggle section starts around line 23582 in the `semantic.css` stylesheet.

You will see this comment:

```
/*--------------
     Toggle
---------------*/
```

Then I copied the CSS below that comment up until the Dimmer section (around line 23760):

Here is the CSS I copied:

```
.ui.toggle.checkbox {
  cursor: pointer;
  min-height: 1.5rem;
}

.ui.toggle.checkbox .box,
.ui.toggle.checkbox label {
  min-height: 1.5rem;
  padding-left: 4.5rem;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.ui.toggle.checkbox label {
  padding-top: 0.15em;
}

/* Switch */

.ui.toggle.checkbox .box:before,
.ui.toggle.checkbox label:before {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0rem;
  z-index: 1;
  border: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  width: 3.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 500rem;
}

/* Handle */

.ui.toggle.checkbox .box:after,
.ui.toggle.checkbox label:after {
  background: #ffffff -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05));
  background: #ffffff linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05));
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(39, 41, 43, 0.15) inset;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  top: 0rem;
  left: 0em;
  border-radius: 500rem;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease 0s,
    left 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: background 0.3s ease 0s,
    left 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.ui.toggle.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] ~ .box:after,
.ui.toggle.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] ~ label:after,
.ui.toggle.checkbox input[type="radio"] ~ .box:after,
.ui.toggle.checkbox input[type="radio"] ~ label:after {
  left: -0.05rem;
}

/* Focus */

.ui.toggle.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:focus ~ .box:before,
.ui.toggle.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:focus ~ label:before,
.ui.toggle.checkbox input[type="radio"]:focus ~ .box:before,
.ui.toggle.checkbox input[type="radio"]:focus ~ label:before {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: none;
}

/* Hover */

.ui.toggle.checkbox .box:hover::before,
.ui.toggle.checkbox label:hover::before {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: none;
}

/* Active */

.ui.toggle.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .box,
.ui.toggle.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label,
.ui.toggle.checkbox input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .box,
.ui.toggle.checkbox input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label {
  color: #5bbd72;
}

.ui.toggle.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .box:before,
.ui.toggle.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:before,
.ui.toggle.checkbox input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .box:before,
.ui.toggle.checkbox input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label:before {
  background-color: #5bbd72;
}

.ui.toggle.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .box:after,
.ui.toggle.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:after,
.ui.toggle.checkbox input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .box:after,
.ui.toggle.checkbox input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label:after {
  left: 2.05rem;
}

/*******************************
            Variations
*******************************/

/*--------------
     Fitted
---------------*/

.ui.fitted.checkbox .box,
.ui.fitted.checkbox label {
  padding-left: 0em !important;
}

.ui.fitted.toggle.checkbox,
.ui.fitted.toggle.checkbox {
  width: 3.5rem;
}

.ui.fitted.slider.checkbox,
.ui.fitted.slider.checkbox {
  width: 3.5rem;
}

/*******************************
         Theme Overrides
*******************************/

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Checkbox';
  src: url(data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;base64,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) format('truetype'), url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,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) format('woff');
}

.ui.checkbox label:before,
.ui.checkbox .box:before,
.ui.checkbox label:after,
.ui.checkbox .box:after {
  font-family: 'Checkbox';
}

.ui.checkbox label:after,
.ui.checkbox .box:after {
  content: '\e800';
}
```

Don't copy beyond this comment:

```
/*******************************
            Dimmer
*******************************/
```

I then replaced the corresponding markup in my version of Semantic UI with the above CSS and it the toggle checkbox appeared with the green styling as shown in the first picture above.

Maybe this will help someone who has been using a previous version of Semantic UI.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a jsfiddle for that. Link: http://jsfiddle.net/nirjhor/eyugtamp/
Make sure that you have linked jquery and semantic.js on your app as this is prerequisite. And in a external .js file you have to call the function `checkbox()`. I think that'll help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using an alpha version.

Answer (score 0):

The following simple code is working fine for two different toggle buttons with onClick event.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../dist/semantic.css">
<script src="../assets/library/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../dist/semantic.js"></script>

</head>
<script>

function show(b){
alert( $(b).hasClass("active"));
}

// attach ready event
$(document)
  .ready(function() {
  var $toggle  = $('.ui.toggle.button');
  $toggle
    .state({
      text: {
        inactive : 'Vote',
        active   : 'Voted'
      }
    })
  ;

})
;
</script>
<body>

<button class="ui toggle button" onclick="show(this)">
  Vote
</button>
<br/><br/>
<button class="ui toggle button" onclick="show(this)">
  Vote
</button>


</body>
</html>
```